# cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

This is my index.js code

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import "bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { userReducer } from "../src/reducers/UserReducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { loadState, saveState } from "./store/LocalStorage";

const persistedState = loadState();
 
let store = createStore(userReducer, persistedState);

 
store.subscribe(() => saveState(store.getState()));
 
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

This is the error I am getting on browser

"**Error: You cannot render a `<Router>` inside another `<Router>`. You should never have more than one in your app.**"

Please help me with some solution.

Comment: On its own, this code looks fine. But apparently some other component farther down the tree is rendering an additional Router. Try searching your codebase for spots where you import `BrowserRouter`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using React Router 6. They dropped support for nested `Router`s(like `MemoryRouter` inside of `BrowserRouter` or any other combinations)

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7375

There is rather a hack with `<UNSAFE_LocationContext.Provider` but as name suggests it's not guaranteed this will work for any(even patch version) updates.

I suggest you either going back to V5 or getting rid of nesting.